# Import CSV timestamp with space

Tags: csv, timestamp, octave

I have a CSV like this

```
timestamp,H_LOC20 (%RH),T_LOC20 (°C),P_LOC20 (Pa)
23 gen 2023 09:05:50 CET,"46,7","17,3","0,1"
23 gen 2023 09:06:00 CET,"46,7","17,3","0,1"
23 gen 2023 09:06:10 CET,"46,7","17,3","0,1"
23 gen 2023 09:06:20 CET,"46,7","17,3","0,1"
23 gen 2023 09:06:30 CET,"46,7","17,3","0,1"
23 gen 2023 09:06:40 CET,"46,7","17,3","0,1"
```

in Octave i use simple csv2cell to obtain a cell with all column.
How can i use the timestamp in a timeseries data?

I'm trying to use strftime with no luck

Answer (score 0):

`strftime` is for converting a time struct to a string.

You are trying to do the reverse. The corresponding function for that is `strptime`

Note that octave supports two datetime-management systems, a c-based one, and a matlab-compatible one. `strftime` and `strptime` belong to the former. This shouldn't matter to you, of course, unless you want matlab compatible code, in which case you should be having a look at the `datenum`/`datestr`/`datevec` family. You might need to obtain all the date tokens from your string by yourself, via something like `strtok` or `strsplit` for that.

---

<sub>PS. To complicate things further, I believe matlab has now moved on from the above three functions to a 'Date' object based system ... but I haven't used that, and in any case it's not relevant to your situation within octave.</sub>